# php showing just plain text

Tags: php5

I have installed php5 but when I tried for

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I got following output rendered on my browser

```
Hello World'

; ?>
```

why am I getting extra output?
(I am working on `Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca`)

Comment: you need to configure your http server to interpret php

Comment: thanx @Dārayavahuštdi , please can you tell me how would I do that for Linux mint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source of the rendered document, you'll probably see it's actually the whole source of the PHP file. It's interpreting out the `<?php` tags as something that *might* be HTML.

Installing PHP5 isn't enough. Your webserver needs to know what to do with PHP files. That depends on both distribution and your webserver. Given we know neither, and that this is a very common use-case for Linux servers, just look in your distribution's documentation. Here's an example [from the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) that covers a wide array of deployments.

If you're using NGINX or another httpd, you'll want different instructions, but the process is similar.

Comment: thanx @Oli, well how can I do this If I am using Linux mint 17.1 Rebecca?

Comment: @jazzz You should be able to follow the Ubuntu documentation as it's a derivative.